# wordpress php get queries from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, query-string, parse-url

I am making a plugin for wordpress that is located at `companyname.com/event/countdown/`. On this page I would like to dynamically some information from the url string to show a countdown the company can email. So in the url `companyname.com/event/countdown/?city?daysleft` how can I echo out the city and the days left separately? So on the page it would be:

Event at `<?php echo city ?>` is `<?php echo daysleft ?>` days away

I have seen `parse_url` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but I guess I am not fully sure how to get separate parts or build the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't stop the usage of typical super globals.

In this case, you can just use `$_GET['city']` and `$_GET['daysleft']`. The query string should be well formed, unlike yours, observe:

```
/?city=mycity&daysleft=someinteger
```

Comment: Ya, I was not sure on the proper way to form the urls. When I add that url and then tried `<h2><?php $_GET['city'] ?></h2>` in my template it didnt return anything. Am I missing something